# Python how to receive all regex finds?

Tags: python

I'm scraping a website and I am trying to find ALL regex matches, currently I am just able to print out one of them (the first one), how would I go on about finding ALL of them?

```
import requests
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0'
}
response = requests.get("https://hidden.hidden&page=2", headers=headers)

i = 0
while i <= 25:
    result = re.search('user1=(.*)">', response.text)
    print(result.group(1))
    i = i + 1

print("Done. ")
```

I have tried using result[0], without any progress

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's regex `findAll` method, as follows:

```
result = re.findall('user1=(.*)">', response.text)
print(result)
```

result will be a list containing every match found. If you have more groups, however, the return will a list of tupples. You can find more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)